# How can I tell whether I am booted into the A or B partition?

Tags: adb, lineageos, ab-partition

Android can install to an A or a B partition. This seems to be a default these days. How can I tell which one I am booted into using `adb`?

I am using LineageOS 17.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The right-most way (`bootctl`)

The command to provide this information is `bootctl`. As `root` (having run `adb root`), you can use this like this,

```
$ adb shell bootctl get-current-slot
```

Note this is the slot's number, you resolve that to the letter with,

```
$ adb shell 'bootctl get-suffix $(bootctl get-current-slot)'
```

*See also: [How can I boot to a specific partition with ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231140/7425), which also uses `bootctl`*

## Using `getvar`

```
$ adb shell /bin/getprop ro.boot.slot_suffix
_b
```

## From `fastboot`

```
$ fastboot getvar all
```

And find in the output: `(bootloader) current-slot: a`

## Other ways

### From `/proc/bootloader_log`

This command from `adb shell`

```
$ grep -i 'DEBUG: boot_' /proc/bootloader_log
```

Or like this,

```
adb shell "grep -i 'DEBUG: boot_' /proc/bootloader_log"
```

It return output like this,

```
avb_slot_verify.c:325: DEBUG: boot_b: Loading entire partition.
```

I believe that's in reference to the `b` partition that it's booting from.

### From `/proc/cmdline`

You can also parse this out of `/proc/cmdline`

```
$ adb shell 'cat /proc/cmdline | tr " " "\n" | grep -i slot'
androidboot.slot_suffix=_b
```