# How can I boot to a specific partition with ADB?

Tags: adb, ab-partition

If I have ADB access to device, how can I specify the boot partition and reboot. I tried with `setprop` but this failed,

```
#> setprop ro.boot.slot_suffix _b
libc: Unable to set property "ro.boot.slot_suffix" to "_b": error code: 0xb
setprop: failed to set property 'ro.boot.slot_suffix' to '_b'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `bootctl`

Though it requires `adb root`, one method to do this would be to use `bootctl` if available.

```
#> bootctl set-active-boot-slot SLOT
#> reboot
```

**Note: `SLOT` is a number, you can find out the labels by looping through them and calling `get-suffix`** for example this little shell script,

```
for slot in $(seq 0 $(expr $(bootctl get-number-slots) - 1)); do
  echo $slot: $(bootctl get-suffix $slot);
done;
```

Which will return the mapping,

```
0: _a
1: _b
```

*See also: [How can I tell whether I am booted into the A or B partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231113/7425)*